# Wi-Fi network is not showing in Wi-Fi networklistk

Tags: wireless

I have laptop (HP Notebook - 15-ac132ne),I have a problem that if I move the laptop from a Wi-Fi device more than a meter, it don't connect to the Wi-Fi network , and if I move  the laptop from a Wi-Fi device more than two meters, the Wi-Fi network disappear and This problem didn't encounter me when I was using Windows

```
mohamed@mohamed-HP-Notebook:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
0d:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCI
e Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:804c]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
mohamed@mohamed-HP-Notebook:~$
```